# How to effectively load url remote image in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, picasso

Usually we loading picture is on `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem` method.
such as:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error).into(imageView);
```

Images then don't show in ViewPager probably never download. But, I want to pre-download images. I've used `Picasso.with().load(url).downloadOnly`, but this causes multiple unnecessary same url downloading.

I want to pre-download images. If have same url image downloading, it merge downloading interface.

Comment: your english is not good but, Picasso will not download the image again if it's cached. Use Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true); to see where the image is comming from, and you will see only the first time you will get the download, then you should get it from memory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using Glide.It's effective and power.Preload image only use preload() method.

Comment: You should add a working copy to this answer so you can exemplify how you fixed this issue. This is not a proper answer.